# What is the difference between if(!pointer) and if(!*pointer)?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:`const MyStruct* MyClass::MyMethod(void* *iter) {
    if (!iter)
        return NULL;
    if (!*iter) {
        // ...`
What is the difference between the two conditionals?

Comment: Do you know what `*` does when applied to a pointer?

Comment: It's the same as the difference between "is there a house at this address" and "is there anyone in the house at this address".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iter` in your code refers to a pointer to a pointer to void (i.e. pointer to void pointer)

`!iter` checks the address `iter` is referring to and returns true if `iter` hold `NULL` in it.

`!*iter` checks the value stored in the address that `iter` holds, and will return true if it is `NULL`.

in general, the `*` operator is the dereference operator that reads the value inside the address help by a pointer.

Comment: Might also want to note that the test `!*iter` assumes that `iter` is not NULL  (or, more accurately, gives undefined behaviour if `iter` is NULL).